# Is it possible to rotate in Preview without advancing to the next page?

Tags: keyboard, pdf, preview

I have a slight annoyance with rotating pages 180 degrees in Preview. The next page is selected automatically after rotating either left or right (90 degrees).  This behavior adds a step. Is there a way to disable the auto-advance, or perhaps a keyboard command that rotates the page 180 degrees? (I don't want to flip the page vertically.)

Comment: What OS, what version Preview? I can't repro your issue.

Comment: Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.2

Preview Version 8.0 (859.7)

Comment: 10.10.3 & 8.0 859.21 here - not sure of that's what may make the difference